# Bootstrap container content not centered over 1200px viewport width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I'm currently working on a website which you can view on [Pencakova website](http://mcp.pencakova.eu) (testing version.)

I'm having sort of trouble with container in the second part of the website [pencakova second](http://mcp.pencakova.eu#second). See those three photos? They are supposed to be centered in a container, but it does not work if the viewport width is bigger than 1200. What is the problem?

The part of HTML:

```
<div id="pictures" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pic col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <img src="img/pic1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                <p>Best European roasters<br>roast various types of the<br> coffee of the highest quality</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pic col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <img src="img/pic2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <p>From these various types<br> of coffee, we choose<br>four types that fit you best.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pic col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <img src="img/pic3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <p>And finally, we will send you<br>box of best coffee that you<br>can't get anywhere else.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#pictures {
display: block;
margin: 4em 0;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'RalewayLight';
font-size: 1em;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
.pic {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2em;

}
.pic:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}
.pic:last-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.pic img {
    /*max-height: 20%;*/
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    /*max-width: 20px;*/
}
.pic:first-child p {
    padding-right: 0.3em;
}
.pic:last-child p {
    padding-left: 0.3em;
}

    @media (max-width:1500px) and (min-width:800px){ 
        .pic img {
            max-width: 280px;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: And joking about suicide isn't funny.

Comment: "but it does not work if the viewport width is bigger than 1200" - can you describe what exactly what is happening?

Comment: @Trevor I am resizing browser window and if width is smaller than 1200, pictures are centered, but if i make it bigger, they become aligned to left.

Comment: @user3881384 - Instead of adding the .pic p {text-align:center;} like I said before, remove the two rules I specified below in my edit. It's less code and does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html so the div's with class="pic" have 'col-md-4 col-lg-4' like this:

```
<div class="pic col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <img src="img/pic3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  <p>And finally, we will send you<br>box of best coffee that you<br>can't get anywhere else.</p>
</div>
```

And change your .pic rule in your css to this:

```
.pic {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

And finally, remove these rules from your css:

```
.pic:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}

.pic:last-child {
    text-align: left;
}
```